# How to send a mail from my server (Debian) with letsencrypt to a gmail adress using phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, ssl, gmail, phpmailer

I work on a debian 10.

I try to send a email from php and PHPMailer. I try it from a gmail address and a personnal address (with my hostname). The mail is correctly received on another address than gmail but never received on a gmail address.

I have this error :

2020-06-16 11:05:34 1jl7XC-0005gB-E4 <= contact@**********.fr U=www-data P=local S=884 id=a783d2ca0f30bd*********5f9a5c@********.fr
2020-06-16 11:05:34 1jl7XC-0005gB-E4 ** n******.j*****@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp: all hosts for 'gmail.com' have been failing for a long time (and retry time not reached)
2020-06-16 11:05:34 1jl7XC-0005gE-Hj <= <> R=1jl7XC-0005gB-E4 U=Debian-exim P=local S=2206
2020-06-16 11:05:34 1jl7XC-0005gB-E4 Completed

I use let's encrypt to protect my server.

my PHP is :

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//$libMail = 'l********@gmail.com';
//$libMdp = '*******'; 

$libMail = 'contact@********.fr';
$libMdp = '*********'; 

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

      //$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mx0.mail.ovh.net';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $libMail;                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $libMdp;                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom($libMail, 'Locate');
$mail->addAddress('*****@****.com', 'Nico');               // Na
```

Do you have any idea about the reason why sending email to gmail is not OK, what about hotmail for example ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try ssl before? and what did that do?

Comment: @RamondeVries same things. But other error if I change $mail->Host. I don't know which host I have to use. H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [**.***.140.**] TLS error on connection (recv): Resource temporarily unavailable, try again. H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [**.***.140.**]: Remote host closed connection in response to EHLO sd-*******.********.fr H=alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2404:6800:4003:c06::1a] Network is unreachable

Comment: your `$libMail` is where you should get the smtp settings from, if you have a test@gmail.com forexample, you should look into google.com what smtp settings they use, yours is a `.fr` but i cant see what the actual domain is to check. go to that website and find the smtp settings there, you will get a host, username and password

Comment: This has nothing to do with the TLS certificate on your site. It looks like either your DNS is broken, or your hosting provider is blocking access to gmail. Both issues are dealt with in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide. If you want to send *from* a gmail address, you *must* send through gmail and not your hosting provider's mail server. Also, you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, not that it will make a difference here.

Comment: @Synchro OK for PHPMailer. I think the problem come from gmail because I can send email to address from other domains. I made test with my hosting provider and gmail provider. I prefer use my hosting provider to send mail but It could be easier using gmail. What do you think about it ? I will to the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide. Thanks

Comment: @Synchro I found this tutorial https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/ and now I receive all the mails. Thanks